# Why is the lru_cache slower than cache implemented as a dictionary for the following fibonacci calculator?

Tags: python-3.x, caching, fibonacci

Below are two recursive functions that use memoization. cache_fibonacci uses a cache dictionary while lru_cache_fibonacci uses Python's lru_cache decorator. Why is latter so slow?

```
from functools import lru_cache

cache=dict()    
def cache_fibonacci(n):
    return helper_fibonacci(n)

def helper_fibonacci(n):
    if n in cache:
        #Cache already exists
        return cache[n]
    if n==1:
        value=0
    elif n==2:
        value=1
    else:
        #Cache not set
        a=helper_fibonacci(n-1)
        b=helper_fibonacci(n-2)
        value=a+b
    cache[n]=value
    return value

@lru_cache(maxsize=1024)
def lru_cache_fibonacci(n):
    if n==1:
        return 0
    if n==2:
        return 1 
    else:
        a=rec_fibonacci(n-1)
        b=rec_fibonacci(n-2)
        return a+b
```

The runtime outputs are:

Cached-recursive time= 1.4781951904296875e-05

LRU Cached-recursive time= 0.14490509033203125

Comment: A cache dictionary also allows me to use larger numbers before RecursionError. I have the same concern, why is a dictionary so much better?

Answer (score 2):

LRU Cache policy : Evict the least recently used.
How do we achieve this? Well this depends on the actual algorithm but the bottomline is this.

```
Every node/key has an age bit. 
When you access a key x, either get or put, you reset its age to 0.
```

Why? Because **x** was the most recently used and we denote this by setting its age as 0 indicating that it is like a new born key. More recent than others.

But, we need to do one more step here.

```
Increment everyone's age except the one you recently accessed.
```

This is done to signify that all others except **x** are now older than their last age.

All that remains to evict (if size is breached) is to evict the key whose age is the highest. In your case, it will be the 1025th key.

```
In summary, it is the increment-all op that's really costly to implement.
```

Try increasing the cache size and you'd notice better runtime. However, it'll always be lesser than dict. Dict() implementation in Python is a hash-table.